# Spring boot jpa not updating Map field in entity

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have this entity:

```java
public class DemoEntity {
    int Id;
    Map<TypeA,TypeB> mapField;
    Boolean boolField;
}
```

And the usual spring boot dao (*extending CrudRepository and using postgres*), repository and service.

Now in service I tried following scenarios:

```
DemoEntity demoEntity = demoEntityRepository.getById(Id);
```

1. only updating something inside mapField:

```java
demoEntity.getMapField().put(*some key-value*);`
demoEntityRepository.save(demoEntity);
```

2. updating other fields along with mapField:

```java
demoEntity.getMapField().put(*some key-value*);
demoEntity.setBoolField(!demoEntity.getBoolField());
demoEntityRepository.save(demoEntity);
```

3. creating new map and then updating mapField:

```java
Map<....> newMap=new HashMap<>();
demoEntity.setMapField(newMap);
demoEntityRepository.save(demoEntity);
```

After each scenario I manually queried the database and found:

- entity was not updated in scene 1 but is updated in 2 and 3
- no SQL query is being executed for 1st

What I want to know is why is this happening? Is jpa not able to figure out that I updated the map? If so then why?

I was expecting that entity would be saved as usual in all the cases.